# Jest expect exception not working with async

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am writing a test that supposedly should *catch* an exception

```js
describe('unauthorized', () => {
  const client = jayson.Client.http({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: PORT,
    path: '/bots/uuid',
  })

  it('should return unauthorized response', async () => {
    const t = async () => {
      await client.request('listUsers', {})
    }

    expect(t()).toThrow(Error)
  })
})
```

I am pretty sure that `client.request` is throwing an exception but Jest says:

> Received function did not throw

```js
const test = async () => {
 ...
}
```

Is the correct way to check?

## UPDATE

If I change to

```js
expect(t()).toThrow(Error)
```

I got

```sh
expect(received).toThrow(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a function

Received has type:  object
Received has value: {}
```

Comment: You may need to await the `test` function as it's just an unresolved async function at that point, hence why it hasn't thrown.

Comment: Async functions *return promises*, which may reject, they don't throw errors. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#rejects)

```
 it('should return unauthorized response', async () => {
    await expect(client.request('listUsers', {})).rejects.toThrow(/* error you are expecting*/);
 })
```

Or

You can use `try/catch`

```
 it('should return unauthorized response', async () => {
    const err= null;
    try {
      await client.request('listUsers', {});
    } catch(error) {
      err= error; //--> if async fn fails the line will be executed
    }

    expect(err).toBe(/* data you are expecting */)
  })
```

You can check the error `type of` and the `error message`

Comment: You can also use toStrictEqual in place of toBe and add the exception being thrown as argument.
```expect(err).toStrictEqual(Exception);
```